# encountered /parse error solr search exception

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'pk:()': Encountered " ")" ") "" at line 1, column 4.

I am getting this error in solr in my sap commerce cloud project.
how can I fix it?

full error log

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://localhost:8983/solr: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'pk:()': Encountered " ")" ") "" at line 1, column 4.
Was expecting one of:
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <LPARAMS> ...
    "filter(" ...
    <NUMBER> ...
    <TERM> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood the reason for this error. this solr is searching for product by pk. If the products are wrong or the product detail is not opened, solr gives an error to search for products with pk.
If we fix the fields on the products or correct the faulty products, the problem is solved.